# ADMIN BSB Material Design

Tags: html, material-design

I am new to ADMIN BSB Material Design.

Please refer the enclosed screen shot and code how to disable(marked in red) the first display.

```
<div  class="col-lg-1 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
<select >
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Image after selection[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to remove the red marked area.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added CSS plugins and JS plugins for the select. To view select in proper format you have to add required plugins provided.
Now add this plugins:

1. CSS Plugin in head section :

   - `<link href="plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
2. JS Plugin in body section :

   - `<script src="plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>`

This would definitely help.